# Query result as variable in another using jdbc

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, apache-kudu

Because I want to optimize a query, I want to rennounce at a join. Due of that, I need to declare a variable before the main query, but I can't find a solution to use it in jdbc statement.

Original query:

```
SELECT 
  d.orders
  SUM(price * qty) / d.orders
FROM main_table
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT SUM(qty) AS orders FROM main_table
   WHERE status = 1) d
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY d.orders
```

formatted query:

```
SET @orders = SELECT SUM(qty) AS orders FROM main_table WHERE status = 1
SELECT 
  @orders,
  SUM(price * qty) / @orders
FROM main_table
WHERE status = 1
```

I can't find a solution to execute correctly this `formatted` query using `jdbc`. Due of grouping by a variable, I'm not sure this will run correctly. Also, I don't want to split this in 2 separated executions using the results of first in the second because will increase the execution time and queries count.

A part of jdbc code

```
val statement = conn.prepareStatement(query)
val rset = statement.executeQuery()
if (rset.next()) {
   // read results
}
```

This is executed every 10 seconds because is used in a realtime dashboard. The db type is `Impala Kudu` (I'm thinking to build the queries as stored procedures, but I'm afraid that Kudu doesn't have support for it). The app is writed in `Scala` but use `jdbc` from `Java` to querying the database.

I already removed some methods from query (decimal casts) to optimize the query and leave it as simple as possible but I still want to remove some unusefull joins there. Is not the only, I have some other similar queries there, so, a small upgrade can have a huge benefit.

thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `GROUP BY @orders` isn't it be only one group?

Comment: Yep, you're right, I removed it from the second query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use

```
SELECT 
  SUM(qty),
  SUM(price * qty)
FROM main_table
WHERE status = 1
```

When you get result just divide second value by first value in you java code.

Or even better:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(price * qty) / SUM(qty)
FROM main_table
WHERE status = 1
```